# How would I echo selected form values in an HTML element (like a p tag)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to show/echo form values in an HTML element as the user fills out a form?

I am creating a giant search form and would like to add a helpful area by the submit button that reminds the user of what they are about to search for.

Comment: yes, with javascript and perhaps or perhaps not using ajax

Comment: please try something then after ask for the help

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example of how you could copy the value of the form inputs with jQuery.

```
$('input[name=query]').keyup(function() {
    $('#query-term').text($(this).val());
});

$('select[name=category]').change(function() {
    $('#query-category').text($(this).val());
}).change();
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFstk/). Here are a list of the jQuery functions I used.

1. `$()` is equivalent to [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
2. [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
3. [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
4. [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php and server (for example apache) configuration has inline php enabled in html/htm/xhtml files, you can include php like this:

```
<..>
<form>
<input>
<?php
echo 'test'
?>
</form>
<..>
```

Same can be put into file .php insted of .htm and would work, because most likely your server enables php parsing just for .php files.

Now if you want to just show form field value which user enters into some field on top of the page, maybe you want this instead:

```
<form>
<input id="search" value="test" onkeypress="$('#search_field_test').text($(this).val())" >
<..>
<span id="search_field_test">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a change handler to the form itself - change events on the individual fields will bubble up (jQuery ensures this even though it doesn't happen naturally in older IE) - and then get all of the non-blank values and put them in your "helpful area" element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $form = $("#yourFormIdHere"),
        $formFields = $form.find(":input"),
        $helpfulArea = $("#yourOutputElement");

    $form.change(function(e) {
        $helpfulArea.empty();
        $formFields.each(function() {
            if (this.value != "")
                $helpfulArea.append(this.name + ": " + this.value + "<br/>");
        });
    });
});
```

The [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) gives you all form controls, but you'd need to add some code to handle checkboxes and radio buttons differently because you'd include them in your output based on their `checked` property, not on their `value` property. As you can see I'm just using the input element name attribute as a label in the output, but you could pretty this up by using the text from the associated label element (if there is one), or add a `data-displayName=...` attribute or whatever. But this should be more than enough to get you started...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/3VB6G/

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to check out [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), which would allow you to do things like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```